# Create files from text list using command line?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I know that normally you can just use `touch filename` to create new files via command line.  But, in the text file I have a list of about 500 cities and states, each on a new line.  I need to use command line to create a new text file for each of the cities/states.  For example, Texas.txt, New York.txt, California.txt

The name of the file that contains the list is newcities.txt - Is this possible to do in command line or through Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a simple:

```
cat fileName | xargs touch
```

Comment: Better: `xargs touch < fileName`

Comment: Better: xargs -a filename touch

Comment: In the original question's example, "New York" will produce 2 files: "New" and "York".

Answer (score 3):

You can do this directly in the shell, no need for perl

```
cat myfile | while read f; do echo "Creating file $f"; touch "$f"; done
```

Comment: For your case Youns solution would be shorter. I prefer this one, because you can include sa many complex commands on a single line as you want, sperated by ';', even using if etc..

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lnwe 'open my $fh,">", "$_.txt" or die "$_: $!";' cities.txt
```

Using the `-l` option to autochomp the input. The `open` will create a new empty file, and the file handle will be autoclosed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Unlike most other answers, this will not immediately produce sh*t because of simple spaces. Still, adding something like `s/[\/\&\|;]+/-/g` would be better, and could probably be extended to be more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner in `perl`, assuming each city is on a new line

```
perl -ne 'chomp; `touch $_`;' newcities.txt
```

Here's the script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "./newcities.txt"
  or die "Cannot open file: $!";

while( my $line = <$fh> ){
    chomp $line;
    system("touch $line");
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: You don't need `./` in front of your file name.

Comment: gaah, you're letting the shell do horrible things with the names.  Use this: `perl -lne 'system touch => $_' newcities.txt`

Comment: @JulianFondren What are you talking about? It's not clear what your improvement is? The fact that `-l` auto chomps? Why on earth would you want a "fat-comma", is there a special use for it here? If not, it just looks out of place. eg You're not going to have some list like this: `my @l = ('a' => 'b' => 'c');`. I mean you *could*, but you shouldn't.

Comment: `$line = 'haha; rm -rf /'; system("touch $line");`